# Run jQuery function in PHP Function File

Tags: php, jquery

How to add jQuery function in PHP function File?

Example :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.livequery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.timeago.js"></script>
<?php
class db{
public $db;

function get_news()
{
bla bla
}
}
```

When run the code, the jQuery is not working. Please help.

Thank you

Comment: Where is the jquery code? Here you just load two JS files

Comment: Sorry, just updated the code. That include jQuery.min.js but still cant working

Comment: Its only a jquery file you include. After that you should execute Jquery function inside script tag

Comment: @hiDayurie **Please read [this post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming)**

Answer (score 1):

You can't run jQuery function in PHP. You can run them from HTML. First close php:

```
?>
<script>
    function get_news() { blabla; }
</script>
<?php
```

If this is not what you're looking for then there is no way for you to do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      alert("Test");
     });
</script>

<?php
   echo "PHP code here";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Echo jQuery function call to run it

```
<?php
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert(\"Test\");
 });
</script>";
?>
```